# Check WordPress login outside current domain

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, cross-domain

In a PHP website (no WordPress) I want to check if current visitor is already and previously logged in another WordPress blog (different folder or domain).

I use this code:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../wp-blog-header.php');
if(!is_user_logged_in())
{
exit('You do not have access');
}
```

It works correctly if PHP site is in this path

> example.com/site/index.php

but I get Error 500 if I use it in

> SUBDOMAIN.example.com/index.php

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('httpS://www.example.com/wp-blog-header.php');
if(!is_user_logged_in())
{
exit('You do not have access');
}
```

Is it possible to do a cross-domain check?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue when I was creating a sub-domain to display a certain page off my site.  I wasn't getting a 500 error but the page would load and the user would not be logged in.  The reason is because wordpress sees the sub-domain as it's own domain and thus would not try to load/access the same cookies.  I ran across this post:

**https://github.com/dellis23/django-wordpress-auth/issues/6#issuecomment-130070419**

You basically have to add **COOKIE_DOMAIN** and **COOKIEHASH** into you wp-config file and set them to the root domain of the wordpress you want to get the cookie information from.  Setting it this way should allow your whole domain to be able to access the cookie info.

I don't really know why your getting a 500 error though.  Maybe it's how you trying to get the wp-blog-header.php.  I don't think you can just type in the actual address with "https://www" and all but need to access it using something like "../example.comDomainDirectory/wp-blog-header.php" or "../example.comDomainDirectory/wordpressInstallDirectory/wp-blog-header.php"

Hopes this helps you in your endeavor!
Cheers